# i get the 'cannot find module' error when running npx create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio, npm, node-modules

i am trying to create my first react project on vscode, firstly i ran the `npx create-react-app react-projects` command i got the following error:

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall lstat
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Admin-Natasha\AppData\Roaming\npm
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\Users\Admin-Natasha\AppData\Roaming\npm'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\Admin-Natasha\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-03-13T15_39_10_215Z-debug-0.log
```

i uninstalled npm and deleted the node_modules file, then tried to run the create-react-app again, i got the following error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'through2'
at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1048:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:901:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1115:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:130:18) 
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1241:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1295:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1091:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:938:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1115:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'C:\\Users\\Admin-Natasha\\AppData\\Local\\npm-cache\\_npx\\c67e74de0542c87c\\node_modules\\hyperquest\\index.js',
    'C:\\Users\\Admin-Natasha\\AppData\\Local\\npm-cache\\_npx\\c67e74de0542c87c\\node_modules\\create-react-app\\createReactApp.js',
    'C:\\Users\\Admin-Natasha\\AppData\\Local\\npm-cache\\_npx\\c67e74de0542c87c\\node_modules\\create-react-app\\index.js'
  ]
}
```

after uninstalling npm and removing the node_modules, i expected the `npx create-react-app react-projects` to run and start installing but it only loads for 50% and then shows the following multiple lines:

```
(node:13488) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 close listeners added to [TLSSocket]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:13488) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 close listeners added to [TLSSocket]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
```

can anyone please assist, i dont know what to do at this point and i am not really familiar with the errors i keep getting, dont even know how to fix the issue